# Query Two Near Dates with Firestore not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a booking chatbot
and i want to know the two near availables dates to booking if one date is not available.

I had tryied with

```
db.collection("horaries")
            .where("startat", "==", dateTime)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                    return db.collection("horaries")
                        .where("startat", "<", dateTime)
                        .where("startat", ">", dateTime)
```

But it is returning empty all the time, it is work when dont have the where twice, but when i add the other where clause to make != clause it is returning empty. 
How can i make it work?
And if this is not possible anymore, 
what approach can i do?
i want to give the near date to expected booking date, sometimes the nearest it is on top and sometimes the nearest it is on bot so i really want to do this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add multiple conditions to a query in Firestore, the conditions are combined with an AND operation. So your query is asking for `horaries` start before `dateTime` **AND** after `dateTime`. This is an empty set, because no single value can be before and after at the same time.

The common approach to get a single closest item is to combine two queries: one that queries for the first item before, and *another* that queries for the first item afterwards:

```
db.collection("horaries")
  .where("startat", "<=", dateTime)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
      db.collection("horaries")
        .where("startat", ">", dateTime)
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
          ...
```

As you can see, this uses the same number of queries as you already have, since I combined the equality check into the first query.